# sql group by sub group

Tags: sql

I am trying to work out the majority sub group of a group. For an example let's say my table looks like this:

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
|   city      |  car_colour |  car_type |  qty   |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| ------------------------------------------------ |
| manchester  |  Red        |  Sports   |  7       |
| manchester  |  Red        |  4x4      |  9       |
| manchester  |  Blue       |  4x4      |  8       |
| london      |  Red        |  Sports   |  2       |
| london      |  Blue       |  4x4      |  3       |
| leeds       |  Red        |  Sports   |  5       |
| leeds       |  Blue       |  Sports   |  6       |
| leeds       |  Blue       |  4X4      |  1       |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

I've tried to find a pure sql solution so that i can see: in each city, which colour of car has the largest quantity.

I can do:

```
select city, cars, sum(qty)
from table
group by city, cars
```

to get:

```
+------------+------+----+
| manchester | red  | 16 |
| manchester | blue |  8 |
| london     | red  |  2 |
| london     | blue |  3 |
| leeds      | red  |  5 |
| leeds      | blue |  7 |
+------------+------+----+
```

but is there anyway i can use a sub query to get the max of the results which would return the max colour for each city, so the results would show:

```
+------------+------+
| manchester | red  |
| london     | blue |
| leeds      | blue |
+------------+------+
```

I can do these calculations in my Python script but would prefer a pure SQL solution.

Hope this makes sense, thanks for any help in advance :)

Tommy

Comment: Which RDBMS you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select distinct p.city, p.car_colour,sq.qty as qty
from         ( select t.car_colour,t.city, sum(t.qty) as qty
                from table1 t
                group by t.car_colour,t.city
             )p
join         ( select q.city,max(q.qty) qty from
                  ( select t.car_colour,t.city, sum(t.qty) as qty
                   from table1 t
                   group by t.car_colour,t.city
                  )q
                 group by q.city
              )sq
on p.city=sq.city and p.qty=sq.qty
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1baeb/44)

Comment: Maybe i'm doing something wrong but because this solution still groups by city AND car, i don't get 1 record for each city, i still get one record for each car_colour for each city. I want find the max of the sub query for each city and see which colour this is. The problem is if i include q.car_colour in the SELECT statement it must be either group by or aggregate. Is there any way to make the max(q.qty) take precedent over whatever aggregate function i put on q.car_colour?

Comment: I am really sorry, I din't noticed well, just let me to review again and edit my answer

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas, I see yes you have posted a wrong answer, please don't advertise for your wrong answer under my answer

Comment: @TommyGaboreau my apologize, the typos fixed, I tested the query also please check it again.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas do you see how it works like a charm!!??? it is much better than your wrong solution which you edited the sample data of OP and given an answer

Answer (score 3):

In case you use MS SQL:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      city NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
      color NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
      qty INT
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 'manchester', 'Red', 7 ),
        ( 'manchester', 'Red', 9 ),
        ( 'manchester', 'Blue', 8 ),
        ( 'london', 'Red', 2 ),
        ( 'london', 'Blue', 3 ),
        ( 'leeds', 'Red', 5 ),
        ( 'leeds', 'Blue', 6 ),
        ( 'leeds', 'Blue', 1 )


SELECT  city , color
FROM    ( SELECT    city ,
                    color ,
                    SUM(qty) AS q ,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY city ORDER BY SUM(qty) DESC ) AS rn
          FROM      @t
          GROUP BY  city , color
        ) t
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Output:

```
city        color
leeds       Blue
london      Blue
manchester  Red
```

Comment: thanks you made my day with that clear and elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

This works, but it can probably be improved depending on what specific database you are using:

```
select t.city, t.car_colour, a.qty
from table1 t
join (
  select city, max(qty) qty 
  from (
    select city, car_colour, sum(qty) qty 
    from table1 
    group by city, car_colour
  ) x group by city
) a on t.city = a.city 
group by t.city, t.car_colour, a.qty
having sum(t.qty) = a.qty
order by t.city desc;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1baeb/11)